# Kotlin RxJava2 onError not called for Http status code 400

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2, okhttp

I'm using RxJava2 with Retrofit and OkHttp in Android application that I'm working on.

For this app I am using Kotlin, not that it makes any difference whether it's Java or Kotlin.

In previous apps that I've worked on, when the server returns a **400** error code, the onError callback is called. However today while working on this setup, the onError callback only fires when for example the server is down but `onNext` is called even for **400** error codes.

below are extracts from my setup

```
/**
 * Networking
 */
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0"
/**
 * Rx
 */
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0"
```

This is an extract from a dagger2 module which actually builds the retrofit object

```
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
                        gson: Gson,
                        @BaseUrl baseUrl: String): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
    }
```

This is the actual code that calls the API

```
fun loginUser(username: String, password: String): MutableLiveData<Result> {
        if (username.isNotBlank() && password.isNotBlank()) {
            subscriptions.addAll(remoteUserRepository
                    .getUser(UserDto(username, password))
                    .subscribeBy(onNext = {
                        saveUser(it.body())
                        saveAuthenticationToken(it.headers().get("token"))
                    }, onError = { handleError(it) }))
        }
        return resultLiveData
    }

    private fun saveUser(user: User?) {
        user?.let {
            localUserRepository.saveUser(it)
            resultLiveData.value = Result.SUCCESS
        }
    }

    private fun saveAuthenticationToken(token: String?) {
        token?.let { localUserRepository.saveToken(it) }
    }

    override fun handleError(error: Throwable) {
        super.handleError(error)
        resultLiveData.value = Result.FAILURE
    }
```

This is a log from a request and response to the server which clearly shows that the server is returning an http code 401

```
   D/OkHttp: --> POST http://10.0.2.2:3000/login http/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 48
    Host: 10.0.2.2:3000
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    User-Agent: okhttp/3.11.0
    --> END POST
D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized http://10.0.2.2:3000/login (20ms)
    content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    cache-control: no-cache
    content-length: 94
    Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2018 13:55:07 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive
    <-- END HTTP
```

Even though the server is returning a 401 error, the `handleError(error: Throwable)` callback is never called. It is only called in case the server is not reachable.

What am I missing?

Comment: onError is only called for errors. While 4xx represents an unsuccessful call as far as data goes, it is not erroneous of nature. You can distinguish between successful and unsuccessful calls in the success callback (onNext or something) using `Response<T>#isSuccessful()`

Comment: @TimCastelijns how is it done in here: https://medium.com/mindorks/rxjava2-and-retrofit2-error-handling-on-a-single-place-8daf720d42d6 plus I remember in RxJava1 onError was also called for 400 status code responses. Do you have any idea if this behavior was changed?

Comment: as you can see this example you link to only handles errors with the call itself, not "errors" with the transmitted data

Comment: but he's checking for ```if (e instanceof HttpException)``` which happens with transmitted errors, or am i mistaken?

Comment: it's easiest to just check it for yourself. Attach a debugger, trigger a 401 response and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

`onError` does catch errors which occur due to execution of the task or handling the result.

In your case retrofit call is ok.

You have to handle the result of response:
In your `onSuccess` check if response `isSuccessful` and move on

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the behavior faced was correct because of the following:

```
@POST("/login")
fun login(@Body userDto: UserDto): Observable<Response<User>>
```

as you can see that the return type of the function is `Observable<Response<User>>` more precisely `Response<User>`

So whenever a response is received irrespective of the http status code, `onNext` is called. The only time `onError` is called when a response can't be received.

So in the case where you want a `Response` back, you will need to use the method suggested by @MaxAves

If you want `onError` to be called when your server returns a 400 error code you will need to modify the interface so that it becomes like the following:

```
@POST("/login")
fun login(@Body userDto: UserDto): Observable<User>
```

In my case this is not doable because I need access to the response headers.